# Problem while converting JSON to Swift "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Tags: json, swift, jsonconvert

When I am converting JSON from coinapi.com (https://rest-sandbox.coinapi.io/v1/assets/?apikey=72869C8A-D49B-4DC5-9A3B-17D9804AEE97) I am getting a problem "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format".

As result at the end after converting I have:

```
struct CryptListStruct: Codable {

    let assetID, name: String
    let typeIsCrypto: Int
    let dataQuoteStart, dataQuoteEnd, dataOrderbookStart, dataOrderbookEnd: String
    let dataTradeStart, dataTradeEnd: String
    let dataSymbolsCount: Int
    let volume1HrsUsd, volume1DayUsd: Double
    let volume1MthUsd: Int
    let priceUsd: Double?
    let idIcon, dataStart, dataEnd: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetID = "asset_id"
        case name
        case typeIsCrypto = "type_is_crypto"
        case dataQuoteStart = "data_quote_start"
        case dataQuoteEnd = "data_quote_end"
        case dataOrderbookStart = "data_orderbook_start"
        case dataOrderbookEnd = "data_orderbook_end"
        case dataTradeStart = "data_trade_start"
        case dataTradeEnd = "data_trade_end"
        case dataSymbolsCount = "data_symbols_count"
        case volume1HrsUsd = "volume_1hrs_usd"
        case volume1DayUsd = "volume_1day_usd"
        case volume1MthUsd = "volume_1mth_usd"
        case priceUsd = "price_usd"
        case idIcon = "id_icon"
        case dataStart = "data_start"
        case dataEnd = "data_end"
    }
}
```

I think it is because of a lot of data there and they are not the same. How can I get the correct model?

That's how my function looks like:

```
    
    
    func getCryptList(_ completion: @escaping (CryptListStruct) -> Void, _ error: @escaping (String) -> Void){
    let header: [String: String] = [:]
       self.get(url: "https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/?apikey=367FB27A-371B-4DBD-AB81-E98AAFE857B2", header: header, completion: {
            (data) in
            do {
                guard let data = data else {return}
                let crpytList = try JSONDecoder().decode(CryptListStruct.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(crpytList)
                }
            } catch let err {
                       error(err.localizedDescription)
                   }
               }, error: error)
    }
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**

## never `print(error.localizedDescription)`.

**in a `JSONDecoder` catch block. You get a generic but quite meaningless error message.**

Always print the entire error, `DecodingError`s are very descriptive

```
print(error)
```

---

Your code contains three major errors, one of them (error #3) occurs multiple times

Error #1

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "**Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.**", underlyingError: nil))

indicates that the root object is an array, the JSON starts clearly with `[`

**Solution:** Decode `[CryptListStruct].self`

---

Error #2

> dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "volume_1mth_usd", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "***Parsed JSON number <3699822674922524.74> does not fit in Int***.", underlyingError: nil))

indicates that the received value `3699822674922524.74` is actually a `Double`.

**Solution:** Declare

```
let volume1MthUsd: Double
```

---

Error #3

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id_icon", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 4", intValue: 4)], debugDescription: "**No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "id_icon", intValue: nil) ("id_icon").**", underlyingError: nil))

indicates that the key `id_icon` is missing (at least) in the 5th item of the array.

**Solution:** Declare the type as optional

```
let idIcon : String?
```

The same error occurs for `dataTradeStart`, `dataTradeEnd`, `dataQuoteStart`, `dataQuoteEnd`, `dataOrderbookStart`, `dataOrderbookEnd`, `dataStart`, `dataEnd`

```
let dataQuoteStart, dataQuoteEnd, dataOrderbookStart, dataOrderbookEnd: String?
let dataTradeStart, dataTradeEnd : String?
let dataStart, dataEnd: String?
```

---

Side note:

You can delete the entire CodingKeys enum if you replace `assetID` with `assetId` and add the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let crpytList = try decoder.decode([CryptListStruct].self, from: data)
```

Comment: It worked for me can you see error concretely

Answer (score 0):

try this (note the optionals, and volume1MthUsd: Double), works for me:

```
struct CryptListStruct: Codable {

    let assetID, name: String
    let typeIsCrypto: Int
    let dataQuoteStart, dataQuoteEnd, dataOrderbookStart, dataOrderbookEnd: String?
    let dataTradeStart, dataTradeEnd: String?
    let dataSymbolsCount: Int
    let volume1HrsUsd, volume1DayUsd, volume1MthUsd: Double
    let priceUsd: Double?
    let idIcon, dataStart, dataEnd: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetID = "asset_id"
        case name
        case typeIsCrypto = "type_is_crypto"
        case dataQuoteStart = "data_quote_start"
        case dataQuoteEnd = "data_quote_end"
        case dataOrderbookStart = "data_orderbook_start"
        case dataOrderbookEnd = "data_orderbook_end"
        case dataTradeStart = "data_trade_start"
        case dataTradeEnd = "data_trade_end"
        case dataSymbolsCount = "data_symbols_count"
        case volume1HrsUsd = "volume_1hrs_usd"
        case volume1DayUsd = "volume_1day_usd"
        case volume1MthUsd = "volume_1mth_usd"
        case priceUsd = "price_usd"
        case idIcon = "id_icon"
        case dataStart = "data_start"
        case dataEnd = "data_end"
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

this is how I tested my answer:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cryptList = [CryptListStruct]()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(cryptList.count > 0 ? "fetched \(cryptList.count)" : "fetching...")
            .task {
                cryptList = await fetchThem()
                print("\n----> cryptList: \(cryptList.count) \n")
            }
        // using closure
        //.onAppear {
        //    getCryptList() { list in
        //        cryptList = list
        //    }
        // }
    }
    
    private func fetchThem<T: Decodable>() async -> [T] {
        var url = URL(string: "https://rest-sandbox.coinapi.io/v1/assets/?apikey=72869C8A-D49B-4DC5-9A3B-17D9804AEE97")!
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: URLRequest(url: url))
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print(URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return []
            }
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2: using closure style:

```
private func getCryptList(_ completion: @escaping ([CryptListStruct]) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://rest-sandbox.coinapi.io/v1/assets/?apikey=72869C8A-D49B-4DC5-9A3B-17D9804AEE97")!,
                               completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription as Optional)")
            return
        }
        do {
            let cryptList = try JSONDecoder().decode([CryptListStruct].self, from: data)
            completion(cryptList)
        }
        catch {
            print(String(describing: error))
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Why do you change the type to optional although most of the keys are clearly in **all** dictionaries?

Comment: no there are not. But if you want you can try without optional. Let us know if it works.

Comment: not working. still problem 
"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer with some var not optional. Also you must decode an array of CryptListStruct, like: [CryptListStruct]. Works without any problem for me. To be sure, show us how you decode the response

Comment: @NurjanAbabakirov Please take my advice to print only the `error`.

Comment: PS. once you have this working change your apikey.

Comment: when  i am printing error i have: (Function)

Comment: as I said in my commect, you have to decode `[CryptListStruct].self` not `CryptListStruct.self`. You also have to return `[CryptListStruct]`

Comment: @NurjanAbabakirov Replace `catch let err { error(err.localizedDescription)` with `catch {  print(error)`. —- `catch let something` is Swift 2 legacy.

Comment: updated my answer using old style closure. Take @vadian advice and print your errors.

Comment: What's an "old style closure" supposed to mean?

Comment: Network requests can/must use closure-based asynchronous URLSession APIs 
while the app waits for it to complete. 

With (the new) Swift 5.5, there is IMO a better way, and that is to use async/await.
The async/await as shown in my answer IMO represent a cleaner style compared to the 
older pre-swift 5.5 closure style.

Comment: Sure, good answer. The term "old style closure" of itself doesn't mean that and doesn't communicate anything. Now that I know you mean async/await vs completion handler I'm totally with you. :)

Comment: amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Response Model**

```
typealias CryptResult = [CryptListElement]

// MARK: - CryptListElement
struct CryptListElement: Codable {
    let assetID, name: String
    let typeIsCrypto: Int
    let dataQuoteStart, dataQuoteEnd, dataOrderbookStart, dataOrderbookEnd: String?
    let dataTradeStart, dataTradeEnd: String?
    let dataSymbolsCount: Int
    let volume1HrsUsd, volume1DayUsd, volume1MthUsd: Double
    let priceUsd: Double?
    let idIcon, dataStart, dataEnd: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetID = "asset_id"
        case name
        case typeIsCrypto = "type_is_crypto"
        case dataQuoteStart = "data_quote_start"
        case dataQuoteEnd = "data_quote_end"
        case dataOrderbookStart = "data_orderbook_start"
        case dataOrderbookEnd = "data_orderbook_end"
        case dataTradeStart = "data_trade_start"
        case dataTradeEnd = "data_trade_end"
        case dataSymbolsCount = "data_symbols_count"
        case volume1HrsUsd = "volume_1hrs_usd"
        case volume1DayUsd = "volume_1day_usd"
        case volume1MthUsd = "volume_1mth_usd"
        case priceUsd = "price_usd"
        case idIcon = "id_icon"
        case dataStart = "data_start"
        case dataEnd = "data_end"
    }
}
```

**Decoder Code:**

```
 let result = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(CryptResult.self, from: jsonData)
```

We need to use **CryptResult** instead of **CryptListElement**